# Controller actions appear to be synchronous though on different requests?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2, asynchronous, long-running-processes

I am under the impression that the below code should work asynchronously.

However, when I am looking at firebug, I see the requests fired asynchronously, but the results coming back synchronously:

[image: Requests are handled synchronously]

Controller:

```
[HandleError]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Status()
  {
      return Content(Session["status"].ToString());
  }

  public ActionResult CreateSite()
  {
      Session["status"] += "Starting new site creation";

      Thread.Sleep(20000); // Simulate long running task

      Session["status"] += "<br />New site creation complete";

      return Content(string.Empty);
  }
}
```

Javascript/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/home/CreateSite',
        async: true,
        success: function () {
            mynamespace.done = true;
        }
    });

    setTimeout(mynamespace.getStatus, 2000);
});

var mynamespace = {

    counter: 0,
    done: false,

    getStatus: function () {

        $('#console').append('.');

        if (mynamespace.counter == 4) {
            mynamespace.counter = 0;

            $.ajax({
                url: '/home/Status',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#console').html(data);
                }
            });
        }

        if (!mynamespace.done) {
            mynamespace.counter++;
            setTimeout(mynamespace.getStatus, 500);
        }
    }
}
```

Addtional information:

- IIS 7.0
- Windows 2008 R2 Server
- Running in a VMWare virtual machine

Can anyone explain this? Shouldn't the `Status` action be returning practically immediately instead of waiting for `CreateSite` to finish?

---

Edit:

How can I get the long running process to kick off and still get status updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The web server only runs one request at a time from each user. The requests are queued based on the session id.

(This makes it a lot easier to build web applications, as you don't have to consider the possibility that two threads access the data for the same user at the same time.)

Comment: So, how would I go about getting the async progress status while the long running task goes on?

Comment: @Oded: You create a session-less page that you can request while the other request is running.

Comment: @Oded: Yes, as the page is sessionless you naturally can't use sessions to communicate between the threads. You have to use some other method, like for example a static dictionary of status objects. You have to pick an identifier for the long running thread, for example it's session id, and then send that id in the query string when you get the status so that you can locate the right status object.